# Is it possible to deactivate page-refresh on "F5" keypress using the WPF Modern UI framework from First Floor?

Tags: c#, wpf, modern-ui

Working on an older application from my predecessor which is using the first floor modern ui framework. 
Pretty much by accident we discovered, that the framework tries to refresh the current page when the user presses `F5` key reinitializing the respective `ViewModel`. However, since there are several things triggered from the constructor, this leads to undefined behavior of the application. Additionally the application uses `Oxyplot`, which also leads to problems with data-binding between `PlotView` and `PlotModel` in the `ViewModel`.

What I have tried so far:

- Looking through the source code of the framework so far I couldn't find, where the refresh is triggered, or how to prevent it.
- I tried to assign the `F5` key to another function, in this case as a shortcut to another page, like this:

  ```
  <mui:ModernWindow.InputBindings>
      <KeyBinding Command="{Binding Path=OpenManualCommand}" Key="F5 > 
     </KeyBinding>
  </mui:ModernWindow.InputBindings>
  ```
- [I found an issue on the github page of the framework, describing pretty much the problem I have](https://github.com/firstfloorsoftware/mui/issues/130). However, it didn't get any replies and being from 2016 it probably won't.
- Using the `KeyDown` event and marking it as handled like this:

  ```
  private void UserControl_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
  {
      if (e.Key == Key.F5)
      {
          e.Handled = true;
      }
  }
  ```

  This actually works, however I would have to do the same operation for each view, since it doesn't work if I do it just from the `MainWindow`. Doesn't seem like a good solution to me.

Is there another way, which let me disable the function of the `F5` key with this framework?

Comment: maybe create a base view with the key_down and have the other views inherit?

Comment: @JohnB Yes this is probably the best approach. However the best way would still be to deactivate the refresh in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to disable this using input binding and command. Command in ViewModel was calling a method by Relay which just had empty return statement in its body.